# svn command line when using a file repository instead of a server repository

Tags: linux, svn, raspberry-pi3

I am using a Windows 7 computer and TortoiseSVN to access a file repository on my network shared folder.

Now I want to access the same repository from a command line within `Raspberry PI 3`. I dont know how to give the repository link to the `svn` command line interface.

It seems like svn on my raspy doesn't understand how to interpret:

```
file:///Q:/Projekte/Heimautomation/Subversion-Sicherung/trunk
```

I know, that I have to use a linux-based path, so the given path would be something like:

```
/mount/media/diskstation/Projekte/Heimautomation/Subversion-Sicherung/trunk
```

But I didn't try this because I need to setup `samba` at first.

Some hints would be great.

Greetings, Wolfgang.

Comment: I dont like it, when somebody thinks he can edit my question. It may be not in native english, but i think, that it is still understandable.

Comment: You already know what you need to do - configure your Synology device so that your RPi can access it using a protocol it understands (maybe Samba, maybe something else). So why didn't you do that when you know that's what you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to accomplish this problem was to setup the subversion server as an HTTP server, so the subversion repository is at http://raspy/repo for example

Answer (score 1):

This command should work in case you can authenticate to the network share from Raspberry Pi. Take the `file://` URL as example

`svn info "file://COMPUTER/share/MyRepository"`

But keep in mind that ...

> `file://` access is intended for local, single-user access only,
>   particularly testing and debugging.

That means that you might find easier and more robust to install a Subversion server on your Windows computer and access the repositories via HTTP(S)